# How to filter my json object in different variables

Tags: javascript, json

I want to insert into different variables the following: **name, meetup, tag** from my object.
To put them separately in an array or object.

My json object:
    var data = {
        "MY_ID": 1,
        "module": [
            {
                "name": "Manchester",
                "meetup": "First Monday of every month",
                "tags": [
                    "gtug",
                    "google",
                    "manchester",
                    "madlab"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "jQuery Group",
                "meetup": "First Tuesday of every month",
                "tags": [
                    "jquery",
                    "javascript",
                    "jresig",
                    "madlab"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Hybrid!",
                "meetup": "First Monday of every month",
                "tags": [
                    "jquery",
                    "javascript",
                    "jresig",
                    "madlab"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

Comment: Can you add more details, what you really want to do with name, meetup, tag?

Comment: `alert(data.module[0].name);`

Comment: OP, it looks like you don't know what JSON is. Please read this : http://json.org/

Answer (score 2):

That's not JSON but JavaScript, you don't have any parsing to do.

Comment: how do i filter it then. thanks

Answer (score -1):

if i understood correctly you want to filter all this data in different variables, so here is a script which does that:

```
var $name = [],
        $meetup = [],
        $tags = [];

    $.each(data.module, function(m, n){
        console.log(n.name);
        $meetup.push(n.name);
        $meetup.push(n.meetup);
        $.each(n.tags, function(a, b){
            $tags.push(b);
        });
    });

    console.log($meetup);
    console.log($meetup);
    console.log($tags);
```

Comment: tank you!, yes you got the question.I meant how to filter it